# Why the javascript fetch API changes the request from POST to OPTIONS?

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome-extension

I just want to post the data to the API whenever the User clicks on the link or opens a link.

Below is the JSON format of the data i'm trying to post,

```
{
    "username": "somename",
    "email": "someone@gmail.com",
    "mobile": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "url": "https://www.atatus.com/blog/fetch-api/"
}
```

The manifest.json file is below,

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "UserData save to Chrome",
    "description": "Save the data to the API",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "login.html",
        "defult_title": "UserData save to Chrome"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["url.js", "popup.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "history"
    ]
}
```

Below is the HTML file that's used to pop up the form,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Username" id="id_username" type="text" name="username" required/><br>

    <input class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Email Address" id="id_email" type="email" name="email" required/><br>

    <input class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Mobile" id="id_mobile" type="text" name="mobile" required/><br>

    <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SAVE</button>
</form>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

The popup.js is the javascript file which i'm using to store the data locally to the chrome storage,

```
function saveChanges() {

    var user = document.getElementById("id_username").value;
    var email_id = document.getElementById("id_email").value;
    var mobile_no = document.getElementById("id_mobile").value;

    chrome.storage.local.set({
        'username': user,
        'email': email_id,
        'mobile': mobile_no
    }, function() {
        alert("Data Saved Successfully " + user + " - " + email_id + " - " + mobile_no);
        window.close();
    });
}

document.getElementById("save").onclick=saveChanges;
```

And finally url.js file which runs in the background is below,

```
chrome.storage.local.get({"username": [], "email": [], "mobile": []}, 
function(user) {
    if (!user) {
        alert("You're not logged in.");
    }

    chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function (data) {
        save_api(user, data);
    });
})


function save_api(user, data) {
    alert("Saving data....");
    var user_data = {
        "username": user.username,
        "email": user.email,
        "mobile": user.mobile,
        "url": data.url
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(user_data));

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/extension/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user_data)
    });
}
```

The url for the request is,

```
url(r'^api/extension/$', extension_view.ExtensionAPI.as_view()),
```

Below code is the django views which holds the post method,

```
class ExtensionAPI(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        acc = Account.objects.all()
        return Response(ExtensionSerializer(acc, many=True).data)

    def post(self, request):
        cust_user_name = request.data.get('username', None)
        cust_email = request.data.get('email', None)
        cust_mobile = request.data.get('mobile', None)
        cust_url = request.data.get('url', None)

        account_details = Account.objects.create(
            username=cust_user_name,
            email=cust_email,
            mobile=cust_mobile,
            url=cust_url
        )
        account_details.save()

        return Response({'status': 'success'})
```

Right now the probelm i'm facing is, everything works as per the expectations, except that fetch api. When i try to post the data it changes the type of request from post to options. And the data is also not saving to the database! Please someone help me fix this issue.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` request is probably a CORS preflight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` request is automatically sent by the browser to check the server's response headers, to check the CORS headers.

What you could do is to add your server's domain to the extension's `permissions` list:

```
"permissions": [
         ....
         "http://yourDomain.com/*"
]
```

Or change your server's response headers to allow access from any domain.

Comment: Nice catch @Titus. Thanks for the help